# Next.js 14 with Express Redirect to Specific Page Not Triggering After Successful Authentication

Tags: express, next.js, router

I'm building a e-commerce project from this tutorial using nextjs 14.
[tutorial](https://youtu.be/06g6YJ6JCJU?si=-j2i4lPITkVcb9Ru)
When a user attempts to check out without signing in, the code in the sign-in/page.tsx file employs a conditional check to prompt the user to sign in first before redirecting them back to the /cart page. However, the router.push(/${origin}) function does not behave as expected—it fails to update the URL and go to /cart page accordingly. The url will remain "http://localhost:3000/cart/sign-in?origin=cart".

this is my server.ts

```
import express from 'express'
import { getPayloadClient } from './get-payload'
import { nextApp, nextHandler } from './next-utils'
import * as trpcExpress from '@trpc/server/adapters/express'
import { appRouter } from './trpc'
import { inferAsyncReturnType } from '@trpc/server'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import { IncomingMessage } from 'http'
import { stripeWebhookHandler } from './webhooks'
import nextBuild from 'next/dist/build'
import path from 'path'
import { PayloadRequest } from 'payload/types'
import { parse } from 'url'

const app = express()
const PORT = Number(process.env.PORT) || 3000

const createContext = ({
  req,
  res,
}: trpcExpress.CreateExpressContextOptions) => ({
  req,
  res,
})

export type ExpressContext = inferAsyncReturnType<
  typeof createContext
>

export type WebhookRequest = IncomingMessage & {
  rawBody: Buffer
}

const start = async () => {
  const webhookMiddleware = bodyParser.json({
    verify: (req: WebhookRequest, _, buffer) => {
      req.rawBody = buffer
    },
  })

  app.post(
    '/api/webhooks/stripe',
    webhookMiddleware,
    stripeWebhookHandler
  )

  const payload = await getPayloadClient({
    initOptions: {
      express: app,
      onInit: async (cms) => {
        cms.logger.info(`Admin URL: ${cms.getAdminURL()}`)
      },
    },
  })

  if (process.env.NEXT_BUILD) {
    app.listen(PORT, async () => {
      payload.logger.info(
        'Next.js is building for production'
      )

      // @ts-expect-error
      await nextBuild(path.join(__dirname, '../'))

      process.exit()
    })

    return
  }

  const cartRouter = express.Router()

  cartRouter.use(payload.authenticate)

  cartRouter.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const request = req as PayloadRequest

    if (!request.user)
      return res.redirect('/sign-in?origin=cart')

    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
    const { query } = parsedUrl

    return nextApp.render(req, res, '/cart', query)
  })

  app.use('/cart', cartRouter)
  app.use(
    '/api/trpc',
    trpcExpress.createExpressMiddleware({
      router: appRouter,
      createContext,
    })
  )

  app.use((req, res) => nextHandler(req, res))

  nextApp.prepare().then(() => {
    payload.logger.info('Next.js started')

    app.listen(PORT, async () => {
      payload.logger.info(
        `Next.js App URL: ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}`
      )
    })
  })
}

start()
```

this is my sign-in/page.tsx

```
'use client'

import { Icons } from '@/components/Icons'
import {
  Button,
  buttonVariants,
} from '@/components/ui/button'
import { Input } from '@/components/ui/input'
import { Label } from '@/components/ui/label'
import { cn } from '@/lib/utils'
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod'
import { ArrowRight, Loader2 } from 'lucide-react'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'

import {
  AuthCredentialsValidator,
  TAuthCredentialsValidator,
} from '@/lib/validators/account-credentials-validator'
import { trpc } from '@/trpc/client'
import { toast } from 'sonner'
import { ZodError } from 'zod'
import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'

const Page = () => {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()
  const router = useRouter()
  const isSeller = searchParams.get('as') === 'seller'
  const origin = searchParams.get('origin')

  const continueAsSeller = () => {
    router.push('?as=seller')
  }

  const continueAsBuyer = () => {
    router.replace('/sign-in', undefined)
  }

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<TAuthCredentialsValidator>({
    resolver: zodResolver(AuthCredentialsValidator),
  })

  const { mutate: signIn, isLoading } =
    trpc.auth.signIn.useMutation({
      onSuccess: async () => {
        toast.success('Signed in successfully')

        router.refresh()

        if (origin) {
          router.push(`/${origin}`)
          return
        }

        if (isSeller) {
          router.push('/sell')
          return
        }

        router.push('/')
      },
      onError: (err) => {
        if (err.data?.code === 'UNAUTHORIZED') {
          toast.error('Invalid email or password.')
        }
      },
    })

  const onSubmit = ({
    email,
    password,
  }: TAuthCredentialsValidator) => {
    signIn({ email, password })
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className='container relative flex pt-20 flex-col items-center justify-center lg:px-0'>
        <div className='mx-auto flex w-full flex-col justify-center space-y-6 sm:w-[350px]'>
          <div className='flex flex-col items-center space-y-2 text-center'>
            <Icons.logo className='h-20 w-20' />
            <h1 className='text-2xl font-semibold tracking-tight'>
              Sign in to your {isSeller ? 'seller' : ''}{' '}
              account
            </h1>

            <Link
              className={buttonVariants({
                variant: 'link',
                className: 'gap-1.5',
              })}
              href='/sign-up'>
              Don&apos;t have an account?
              <ArrowRight className='h-4 w-4' />
            </Link>
          </div>

          <div className='grid gap-6'>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
              <div className='grid gap-2'>
                <div className='grid gap-1 py-2'>
                  <Label htmlFor='email'>Email</Label>
                  <Input
                    {...register('email')}
                    className={cn({
                      'focus-visible:ring-red-500':
                        errors.email,
                    })}
                    placeholder='you@example.com'
                  />
                  {errors?.email && (
                    <p className='text-sm text-red-500'>
                      {errors.email.message}
                    </p>
                  )}
                </div>

                <div className='grid gap-1 py-2'>
                  <Label htmlFor='password'>Password</Label>
                  <Input
                    {...register('password')}
                    type='password'
                    className={cn({
                      'focus-visible:ring-red-500':
                        errors.password,
                    })}
                    placeholder='Password'
                  />
                  {errors?.password && (
                    <p className='text-sm text-red-500'>
                      {errors.password.message}
                    </p>
                  )}
                </div>

                <Button disabled={isLoading}>
                  {isLoading && (
                    <Loader2 className='mr-2 h-4 w-4 animate-spin' />
                  )}
                  Sign in
                </Button>
              </div>
            </form>

            <div className='relative'>
              <div
                aria-hidden='true'
                className='absolute inset-0 flex items-center'>
                <span className='w-full border-t' />
              </div>
              <div className='relative flex justify-center text-xs uppercase'>
                <span className='bg-background px-2 text-muted-foreground'>
                  or
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>

            {isSeller ? (
              <Button
                onClick={continueAsBuyer}
                variant='secondary'
                disabled={isLoading}>
                Continue as customer
              </Button>
            ) : (
              <Button
                onClick={continueAsSeller}
                variant='secondary'
                disabled={isLoading}>
                Continue as seller
              </Button>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Page
```

The ways I have tried:

1. I added a console.log() to check the if the `const origin = searchParams.get('origin')`  gets the 'cart' correctly. Result: It catches the 'cart' correctly.
2. I tried to change

   ```js
   if (origin) {
             router.push(`/${origin}`)
             return
           }
   ```

to something like

```js
if (origin) {
          router.push("/cart")
          return
        }
```

still not working.